# Why can't I revert the luminosity on my canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I use canvas to set the luminosity of an image. This work fine, if i set the luminosity only one time. But if i reset the luminosity back to 0, i don't get the default image. I don't know why.

The code that call the effect :

```
var mainEffect = new CanvasEffect(canvas[0]);
var thumbsEffect = new CanvasEffect(thumbs[0]);
luminositySlider.change(function() {
    var intensity = luminositySlider.val();
    mainEffect.apply("luminosity", intensity);
    thumbsEffect.apply("luminosity", intensity);
});
```

This is the code i use, int is gotten from a html slider. The previous luminosity is stored in an array :

```
function CanvasEffect(canvas) {
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;
var stack = [];
var imageData;
var data;

this.apply = function(effect, intensity) {
    imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    data = imageData.data;
    var int = Number(intensity);
    var refresh =  true;
    switch (effect) {
    case "blur":
        refresh = false;
        stackBlurCanvasRGB('canvas', 0, 0,  WIDTH, HEIGHT, int);
        break;
    case "sharpen":

        break;
    case "luminosity":
        console.log("stack['luminosity'] : " + stack["luminosity"]);
        lastInt = (stack["luminosity"] == undefined) ? 0 : stack["luminosity"];
        newInt = int - lastInt;
        console.log("int : " + int, "lastInt : " + lastInt, "newInt : " + newInt);
        for(var i=0;i < data.length;i+=4) {
            data[i] += newInt; //Red
            data[i+1] += newInt; //Green
            data[i+2] += newInt; //Blue
        }
        break;
    case "contrast":
        lastInt = (stack["contrast"] == undefined) ? 0 : stack["contrast"];
        newInt = int - lastInt;
        var factor = (259 * (newInt + 255)) / (255 * (259 - newInt));
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i+=4) {
            data[i] = factor *  (data[i] - 128) + 128; //Red
            data[i+1] = factor *  (data[i+1] - 128) + 128; //Green
            data[i+2] = factor *  (data[i+2] - 128) + 128; //Blue
        }
        break;
    case "negatif":
        console.log("negatif");
        for(var i=0;i < data.length;i+=4) {
            data[i] = 256-data[i]; //Red
            data[i+1] = 256-data[i+1]; //Green
            data[i+2] = 256 - data[i+2]; //Blue
        }
        break;
    case "b&w":
        console.log("b&w");
        for(var i=0;i < data.length;i+=4) {
            var gris = data[i]*0.3 + data[i+1]*0.59 + data[i+2]*0.11;
            data[i] = gris; //Red
            data[i+1] = gris; //Green
            data[i+2] = gris; //Blue
        }
        break;
    case "sepia":
        console.log("sepia");
        for(var i=0;i < data.length;i+=4) {
            var r = data[i]*0.299 + data[i+1]*0.587 + data[i+2]*0.114;
            data[i] = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, r*1.351)); //Red
            data[i+1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, r*1.203)); //Green
            data[i+2] = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, r*0.937)); //Blue
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if(refresh) {
        imageData.data = data;
        ctx.putImageData(imageData,0 ,0);
    }
    // Stores the effect to recalculate if it changes
    stack[effect] = int;
};
```

}

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Image with luminosity max :

[image: Image with luminosity to 100]

Reset image to the original ( luminosity 0):

[image: Reset image to the original]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *burned* the image, [losing information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_(photography)#Highlights). You'll need to reload the image from the file to recover the information of the **overexposed** pixels.

Once the canvas loads an image, it "forgets" the original file, working only with the loaded pixels. When you increased the luminosity, a big zone of that picture lost the information because it went "out of scale". That lost information cannot be recovered unless the picture is reloaded again.

UPDATE: As @GameAlchemist suggests, you can create your own array:

```
var image= new Int32Array(originalByteArray); //Or Float32Array, I'd test both
```

and store a copy of the image there. Then, make all operations against this array and copy   the ouput in the image data, taking only the first 8 bits.

Comment: ok, it's will be a nightmare for performance. If i have multiple filters. I must to reset image and apply all of filters again ?

Comment: using an int32 to expand the dynamic range is possible but requires careful programming to avoid overflow/underflow/rounding issues to occur. Not worth the effort imho.

Answer (score 2):

The r, g, b, a components are, as you know, stored on 8 bits, which is too few bits to allow several operations : On each operation, rounding and clamping will occur.

The solution is to use Float32Array to store the image's components. Then you can perform any kind and number of operation with (almost) no loss in quality.